# Ram not recognized

Tags: asus-laptop

I just got a new laptop to use as a Linux machine, a Asus f555la-ab31.
I am trying to add more ram to it, currently it has 4GB and I'm going to add 4 for a total of 8. The first dim is soldered into the board however there is a slot to add more. I have tried several dimms of ram, the 4gb and a 2 and 8 gb that I know work in other computers, however the os as well as bios is still only showing 4 GB.
Has anyone else had this issue or is this a settings that must be changed when some of the ram is soldered in?

Comment: Check if your computer supports 64bit and if it does check for a BIOS update.

Comment: It is 64 bit, both the processor and the preinstalled windows are 64 bit, I did check the bios and I am told I have a more recent version than the current version on the asus site, unfortunately neither the win flash client or the bios updater will let me switch to an "older" version