# New RAM memory stick not recognized

Tags: memory, linux-mint, lenovo-laptop

I just installed a second RAM stick but it's not being recognized. The DDR and speed matched the stick that was already there so I don't know what's wrong.

I'm using Mint 17.3, 64bit with Mate on a Lenovo g40-80 on UEFI boot. The laptop also has a radeon R5 graphics card.

Here's the output of `lshw -class memory`

```
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 25
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 4GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
          product: SH564128FJ8NWRNSQG
          vendor: AMD
          physical id: 0
          serial: 03190777
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns) [empty]
          product: 99U5469-041.A00LF
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 1
          serial: 03446216
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
```

The second card, which I just bought new from [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008CP5R8K), is listed as empty, but all the other specs are there except for the size. It's supposed to be another 4GiB (although the capacity is not written on it). I swapped this stick with the old one and the problem persists: the new one is listed as empty.

MemTest86 shows no error with the stick, but it also lists 4GB as the total system memory. Even though individually it recognizes both cards as 4GB.

The BIOS also only shows 4GB.

Might be related to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/998354/ram-not-recognized) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the RAM was defective. I tried a different RAM with the same specs (except for the brand that was Crucial) and it worked perfectly.